# symfony post deployment error

Tags: php, symfony

i developed web site with symfony 3 and upload it on a server but when i try to access to config.php file i have this error

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/homepages/26/d729697492/htdocs/Media/vendor/composer/../symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php7.0') in /homepages/26/d729697492/htdocs/Media/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66

and don't understand i search everywhere no good answer .

Comment: Did you install your dependencies, e.g. via `composer install`?

Comment: no upload vendor directory also. in local everything is ok so i decided to upload all directory

Comment: This is a file permission issue. Apply proper read/write file permission to the folders , try full read/write permission to public directories

Comment: sorry but i have the same error after trying

Comment: The dump function (indicated in your error) is only available in debug mode.  You should not have any dump statements in your production code.  But I'm guessing you have deeper issues.  There are several hundred identical questions out there.  Might need to a bit of research.

Comment: hello, i just delete all my files and after re-upload all my files without vendor directory and after i install all my dependencies via composer install it works. thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just delete all my files on server and after re-upload all my files without vendor directory and after i install all my dependencies via composer install it works. thank